# How do i unpack .nukpg package in Octopus Deploy?

Tags: .net-core, nuget, console-application, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I have created a CI/CD process for a .NET Core console app. The steps in TeamCity are

1. Restore the project
2. Build Project
3. Run Tests
4. Publish in Release Mode
5. Pack project
6. Publish to Octopus Nuget feed

In my Octopus Deploy Library, i can see the latest package there with the package version.

However i want to deploy this package to a specific folder on my target server with the .exe and .dlls, but, it seems like Octopus Deploy is only deploying this package as a .nupkg and is not unpacking it.

The question is, is there a process step to unpack this .nupkg and extrackt all the exes and dlls into a directory on the target server from Octopus Deploy ?

Comment: I have no idea if this is helpful, but `nupkg` files are just zip files, so you could unzip it.

Comment: What are your Octopus Deploy steps?  There is a step to deploy a console app.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be using the wrong step in Octopus to deploy the package such as the `Transfer a Package`. If you use the `Transfer a Package` step, Octopus will transfer the package but not extract it.

In order for the package to be extracted, you can use a step like `Deploy a Package`. This step will extract your `.nupkg` and provide the ability to perform variable substitutions and configuration transformations.

This documentation page has some details on the Deploy a Package step which may help.

https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-examples/package-deployments